# How to combine multiple stashes in git

Tags: git, git-stash

This is a pipeline on branch `frontend` over the last two weeks.

| `Stash@{3}` is all code since `Stash@{1}` (excluding the two tiny commits)
| Tiny Commit
| Tiny commit
| Huge bulk commit two weeks ago, now rebased and moved to `Stash@{1}`

My working tree is currently clean.
`Stash@{1}` is the contents from a bulk commit of general development code two weeks ago (this should have been stashed in the first place). This commit was undone and moved to stash.
`Stash@{3}` is the newest work on that tree since `Stash@{1}` (minus a couple of changes that have been committed).

I need to combine these two stashes together in my working tree so I can make a number of commits from this huge pool of work.

I ran `git stash apply stash@{1}` then I tried:

`git stash apply stash@{3}`
`git stash show -p | git stash apply stash@{3}`

but I get 'dirty working tree' in both cases. How can I merge this work together? Because `stash@{3}` is newer, I want it to supersede `stash@{1}` wherever there are conflicts.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can only apply a stash if there are no conflicts with modified files in the working tree, so, first, ensure there are no modified files in `git status`, if there are, commit them. Then do:

```
git stash apply stash@{1}
git commit -a
# Enter your commit message
git stash apply stash@{3}
```

Then you can either make a new commit, or amend the previous one to combine them. You may need to resolve merge conflicts after each apply.

Also, if you ever decide to use `git stash pop` rather than `apply`, note that `stash@{3}` would become `stash@{2}` since the first one was popped off.

Comment: The two stashes are large and contain a lot of overlapping work, which is why I wanted to avoid the commits. Is it possible to just combine them in the working tree, or am I forced to commit these large chunks and then combine 2 crappy commits and split them into ~10 good commits in vim?

Comment: The other thing is: _I don't want to commit all this code_. Significant chunks of it are still for development-only.

Comment: What's the difference between combining them in the working tree and amending? Or doing a `git reset HEAD^` after the second stash is applied? You cannot apply a stash on a dirty working tree, so you *must* commit before applying one, but that doesn't mean you can't undo that commit after you've applied.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall  "You can only apply a stash to a clean working tree" .... is this still up to date and accurate?

Answer (score 155):

It's a little involved, but this almost always works:

1. Pop the first stash

   ```
   $ git stash pop
   ```
2. Temporarily commit the changes from the first stash

   ```
   $ git add . && git commit -am 'WIP'
   ```
3. Pop the second stash

   ```
   $ git stash pop
   ```
4. Undo the temporary commit, keeping the changes it introduced

   ```
   $ git reset --soft HEAD^
   ```

Comment: Took me awhile to appreciate the beauty of this. It works much better than trying to apply a patch, which often fails due to whitespace or file path changes

Comment: Don't forget to reset your file after it to see the unified change in `git diff`, because currently the reseted change is staged and seen separately as `git diff --staged`.

Comment: This seems like the best solution, but I still don't understand why we can't simply pop an existing stash while we have unstaged changes. For example, it would be nice to simply run `git stash pop` followed by `git stash pop`. Perhaps I'm missing something about the git stash internals.

Comment: If popping the second stash gives merge conflicts (which is when two consecutive pops don't work), you also need a `git add <conflicted_files>` after fixing the conflicts.

Comment: @Nakilon alluded to this, but I would add the following as step 5 (entered from the project's root directory): `git reset HEAD .`

Comment: Doesn't work too well if you have changes...

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me.

1. stage the current changes (if nothing in unstaged, skip this step)

   ```
   git add .
   ```
2. apply the stash you wish

   ```
   git stash apply stash@{0}
   ```
3. stage the current changes

   ```
   git add .
   ```

   or `git add <stashed_filename>`
4. Continue step 2&3 multiple times
5. then un stage everything

   ```
   git reset
   ```

DONE!

Comment: So basically do not apply stash on unstaged changes. Thanks!

Comment: So creating a temp "git commit" is not required before applying another/2nd stash.

Answer (score 15):

A better way is to just use `git stash show -p stash@{whatever} > stash-{whatever}.diff` and then use `git apply` for each one.

Comment: This is by far the most straightforward if the changes don't overlap. I feel silly to have to make commits just to merge the content.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz: there always has to be a commit if the content changes. Not silly at all.

Comment: Applying a stash as a patch will work if the stash is fairly trivial but won't work if there have been intermediate, non-trivial whitespace changes or changes in file paths

Comment: @Kirby: you could apply the stashes in a different order and only use the patch method on the simpler one. Better would be to take care not to have large numbers of stashes with complex changes. That's not a safe workflow.

Comment: No need for an intermediate file, just pipe right into `git apply`: `git stash show stash@<n> | git apply -`.

Comment: For four and a half years I had "stask" in there and nobody noticed until now.

Comment: I think you mean with a -p like this: git stash show -p stash@{whatever} > stash-{whatever}.diff. Other than that your answer is the best one

Comment: git apply doesn't seem to work on the output of `stash show -p` output: `error patch failed` however using `patch -p1 stash-{whatever}.diff` worked well, finally a sane'ish way to do this, ai ai.

Comment: Be sure to be in the top-level directory or the `git apply` will silently fail, as I discovered...

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and solved it like this.

Use `git stash pop` to apply one of the stashes. Then create a patch of this stash with `git diff -p > ../stash.diff`. You can then reset your working tree (or stash the changes again), and pop the other stash with `git stash pop stash@{1}`. If you apply your patch at this moment you can 'merge' the two different stashes.

You'll probably have some conflicts to resolve. If all goes well you can then drop the stashed changes.

Comment: Or just pull stash@{1} out as a diff and apply that locally (for example siride's answer and comments) but this works too, thanks!