# Can't pop git stash, 'Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge'

Tags: git, git-stash

So I had a load of changes and some untracked files. I needed to tweak something, so I used `git stash -u`, modified a couple of things, committed those changes, pushed them, and then tried to `git stash pop`.

Because I'd modified a couple of files that I'd stashed, I got the following message:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    file_1.py
    file_2.py
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

This seems odd, I had committed all new changes, my checkout was clean when I ran the command.

It seems the `git stash pop` operation un-stashed half of my changes and the untracked files, but if I try and `git stash pop` again I get output like:

```
some_file.html already exists, no checkout
some_other_file.html already exists, no checkout
yet_another_file.html already exists, no checkout
Could not restore untracked files from stash
```

`git stash show` still shows a list of my stashed changes, but I'm at a loss as to what I do now.

How can I get myself unstuck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot apply stash to working directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508903/cannot-apply-stash-to-working-directory)

Comment: Related when there are local changes: [git stash -> merge stashed change with current changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16613814/2533467)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I got around this, I think it must have been some kind of bug, as my working directory was clean and up to date.

I ran `git checkout .` and after that `git stash apply` worked fine, I got everything back no problems at all. I'd be interested to work out what actually caused it to fail though.

Comment: For the record, doing this still gave the same errors for me even with a clean working directory.

Comment: This worked for me... emphasis on the `.` Can someone explain why this works?

Comment: For the uninformed, the . is an alias for "all non ignored files recursively", not to be confused with *. But it's 5 years ago, so you know this now. @JamieM.

Comment: I had a clean directory too but I was facing the same error, for me this solution didn't worked. I tried a `git stash apply --index` and it worked, can't really explain what this arg do but as per documentation "attempt to recreate the index"

Answer (score 180):

For those who ***do have*** un-committed work, and want to pop their stash without losing that work, here is a way (with thanks to @iFreilicht):

1. Temporarily stage any uncommitted changes:

   ```
    git add -u .
   ```
2. Now you can apply your stash without git complaining (hopefully):

   ```
    git stash pop
   ```
3. Now unstage everything, but leave the files as they are now:

   ```
    git reset
   ```

If step 2 couldn't patch cleanly due to conflicting changes, then you will need to resolve the conflicts manually.  `git diff` should help you find them.  `git mergetool` might help by opening your editor with before and current files.

Comment: Whenever I do this I feel like I'm not using git properly.. Found no alternative though.

Comment: I managed to find a second way: Instead of committing, run `git add <files>` for all files that would be overwritten. Then you can `pop`, and then just unstage again with `git reset HEAD`. This has to be a bug of some sort.

Comment: @Joost Why not stash instead of commit, then turn around and drop the top of the stash stack?

    `git stash save "junk"`
    `git stash drop`
    `git stash pop`

Comment: Very nice @iFreilicht, I have switched to your method instead!

Comment: LastStar007, we want to keep the current "junk", and pop what is in the stash as well.

Comment: This is great, thanks.  It happens.. too often.. that I stash changes because I need to do urgent work on another branch.  Then I go back to the original branch and keep working without popping my stash...  It's a mess.  This totally solves that problem.

Comment: @little_birdie Not sure if this helps, but I use a git-aware-prompt and when I check out a branch it will remind me whether there [was a stash](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/git-aware-prompt/commit/f3e13a4e9dcf491bef77fd52db9cecfa4211b437) made on that branch, nudging me to pop again.

Comment: Ran into a merge conflict...now what

Answer (score 3):

The stash that was made with `-u` needs to have the untracked files cleaned away before being `apply`-ed (and `pop` is just `apply`+`drop`).

Out of general paranoia I'd `mv` the untracked files somewhere safe, then `git stash apply`, check everything carefully, and `git stash drop` once I'm sure I have it all correct. :-)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I'm starting with a clean working directory with no untracked files, there's nothing to `mv` out of the way!

Comment: Hm.  Might be a bug in `git stash` (I've found one before) ... it would be interesting if you can reproduce this, especially with a small example.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. I was using git stash index command to restore a specific stash id. So, I ended up doing a commit of my local changes to local repo. Then git stash index worked for me. And finally I rolled back my commit using git reset (with keep changes). Problem solved.